# How to access 'this' element from event handler passed into scalatags?

Tags: scala, scala.js, scalatags

I'm trying to access the text of the current (`this`) element from within an event handler created with scalatags. Here is what I tried:

```
val onChange = {(e: HTMLElement) =>
  number() = e.textContent.toInt
}: js.ThisFunction

input(`type`:="number", onchange := onChange).render
```

When I debug the above code, nothing is being passed into the `onChange` function. Specifically, if I put this into the function body:  `js.Dynamic.global.alert(JSON.stringify(e))`, it prints `{}`. Also, I get an error that `e.textContent` is null. How do I get it to pass in the javascript `this` element?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is being passed"? I can't see anything wrong in your code snippet.

Comment: If I put this into the function body:  `js.Dynamic.global.alert(JSON.stringify(e))`, it prints `{}`. Also, I get an error that `e.textContent` is null.

Answer (score 3):

I got some clarification on [scala.js gitter](https://gitter.im/scala-js/scala-js), and it turns out you can access the element from within a closure like so:

```
val inputElem = input(`type`:="number").render
inputElem.onchange = {(e: Event) =>
  number() = inputElem.value.toInt
}
```

Comment: Thanks Julie, that's useful!