# Should be using `target` rather than `srcElement` in Scala.js

Tags: scala.js

I have some Scala.js code which works fine when the target-browser is Chrome but not when it is Firefox. I have been told that I should not use `srcElement` but instead `target`. However I can't work out how to access `target`.

```
private def TD(locId: Location, personId: Person): HTMLTableCellElement = {
  val res = td(style := myPeopleTable_td).render
  res.onclick = { (e: dom.Event) => c.clickTD(e.srcElement)}
  res.id = Id(locId, personId).toString
  cells += (Id(locId, personId) -> res)
  res
}
def clickTD(element: Element): Unit = {
  val idOption = Id.parse(element.id)
  idOption.foreach(id => {
    locIdx = Location.indexOf(id.locId)
    personIdx = Person.indexOf(id.personId)
    localSync()
    v.personValueBox.focus()
  })
}
```

By way of explanation `c` is the Controller and `v` is the View. The first method is in the View and and second is in the Controller. The first method is setting up a cell in an HTML table, including what happens when the user clicks on the cell. In `clickTD()` the code needs to know what has been clicked - it needs to somehow get at the HTML element's 'id' which has been pre-set so that model objects can be looked up.

If I try to replace `e.srcElement` with `e.target` this is the result:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\dev\v2\atmosphere\js\target\scala2.11\classes...
[error] C:\dev\v2\atmosphere\js\src\main\scala\simple\View.scala:145: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.scalajs.dom.raw.EventTarget
[error]  required: org.scalajs.dom.Element
[error]     (which expands to)  org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element
[error]     res.onclick = { (e: dom.Event) => c.clickTD(e.target)}
[error]                                                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (atmosphereJS/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 15-Jun-2015 02:14:41
```

Thanks @ochrons, your suggestion of putting `res` instead of `e.target` works. Unfortunately with the other controls I'm having an 'order of instantiation' problem. In the following I am trying to move the commented-out line to where it can see `res`:

```
private def button_TD_Tog(idT: Row): HTMLTableCellElement = {
  val idsStr: String = idT.toString
  val buttonWidget = button(
    style := myToggleButton, 
    name := "button", 
    id := idsStr
    //onclick := { (e: dom.Event) => c.clickToggleButton(e.srcElement)}
  )
  val res = td(style := myToggleButtonCol, buttonWidget).render
  buttonWidget.onclick = { (e: dom.Event) => c.clickToggleButton(res)}
  res.id = idsStr
  buttonTDs += (idT -> res)
  res
}
```

I (think I) need both `res` and `buttonWidget` to exist before assigning to onclick, but the compiler does not recognize onclick. I found myself searching for some API documentation to help me out here. I doubt that it exists (I've found Scala.js documentation to be excellent, but not comprehensive). Perhaps I should be looking to the DOM itself...

And so now to an example of a simple general solution that seems to work for all cases, as per your advice to force types:

```
c.clickPushButton(e.target.asInstanceOf[dom.Element])}
```

Comment: I think this relates to the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819811/how-to-access-to-this-element-from-event-handler-passed-into-scalatags

Comment: What's wrong with simply replacing `e.srcElement` by `e.target` on the `res.onclick =` line?

Comment: @ochrons The link relates but I need to find out at what control the click is coming from, so I need to use the event itself. Julie's solution was to give up on using the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to know that your `td` element has been clicked, then you can directly use `c.clickTD(res)` in the closure. But if there are elements within the `td` that can be clicked, then you can use the event's `target` by just casting it as an `Element`. In such case your inner elements must bubble the click event up to the `td` element.

The DOM is not entirely type-safe, so sometimes you just need to "know" what you are dealing with. The documentation typically assumes JavaScript, so they don't really care about things like type-safety.